# Using c3 js, Is there a way to show more x-axis values when zooming in?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization, c3.js

Using c3 js Data-visualization tool can we dynamically increase the x-axis culling values on zoom-in. d3 js provides this functionality. How can we achieve this with c3js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set parameter `zoom.rescale` like this - https://jsfiddle.net/sgnu7pu8/

And use docs for c3js - http://c3js.org/reference.html#zoom-rescale